# Android: Apollo subscription with RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2, apollo-client, apollo-android

I'm using subscription in Apollo with Rxjava2 as follow

```
Rx2Apollo.from(someApolloCall)
.observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
.subscribe({

  // on success

}, {
  // on failure
})
```

Everything is working well when the network is ok, however when losing connectivity, subscription fails and it doesn't reconnect again?

how should I reconnect in similar scenarios, 
I've been trying using rxjava operation `retryWhen{}` but in vain!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`retryWhen` responds `onError` so as to resubscribe.

The code below retries a limited number of times (3 times and delays each try by 5 counts)

```
response.retryWhen(errors ->
  errors
    .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i)
    .flatMap(retryCount -> Observable.timer((long) Math.pow(5, retryCount), TimeUnit.SECONDS))
);
```

Also, make sure you are subscribing on `subscribeOn.Schedulers.io()` and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` excutes the emission (actions) on Android main thread.

Comment: 'Rx2Apollo.from(someApolloCall)' is a flowable not observable! should i replace observable in your answer with flowable?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Not sure what someApolloCall looks like but yes you can replace with Flowable.

Comment: can you explain how to write this in kotlin, I've been trying since then buy faces alo of errors